# DAO.QueryDef shows incorrect result in MS Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, dao

I have the following stored query in MS Access

```
SELECT 
    tblRegistration.ID, 
    tblRegistration.TypeCode, 
    CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStart]) AS Reg1, 
    CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStop]) AS Reg2
FROM 
    tblRegistration
WHERE 
    (
        (tblRegistration.TypeCode = "T" Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = "S" Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = "F") 
        AND 
        (CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStart]) Between CDate([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStart]) And CDate([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStop]))
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        (tblRegistration.TypeCode = "T" Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = "S" Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = "F") 
        AND 
        (CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStop]) Between CDate([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStart]) And CDate([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStop]))
    );
```

The query, when stand alone executed as query (when the frmRegBilling is loaded with the parameters used by the query) shows the proper result (8 records).

But when the query is executed in VBA, only 2 records are shown. In this case, only the first parameter is validated.

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As Recordset, varData As Variant
Dim intFields As Integer, intRecords As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim rec As String, fld_type As Integer

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1")
qdf.Parameters(0).Value = Eval(qdf.Parameters(0).Name)
qdf.Parameters(1).Value = Eval(qdf.Parameters(1).Name)
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

j = rst.RecordCount - 1
k = rst.Fields.Count - 1
```

Switching the lines Parameter(0) or (1) doesn't help (if of influence for any reason). Why aren't both parameters validated in the query when executed in VBA?

Comment: Is frmRegBilling open when the VBA code runs? Please [edit] your question to explain why the `Eval()` statements are necessary.

Comment: The frmRegBilling is open. The Eval() statements are required since OpenRecordet does not dereference the criteria in the query. Please ref. to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277231/error-3061-query-loses-form-text-value for more info.

Comment: Just a question, but are you determining the lack of expected records by checking the value of j?  DAO Recordsets are prone to incorrect count of records if you don't call rst.MoveLast.  Wonder if it is just that.  Other than that, have you tried debugging by taking out the Eval calls and hardcoding the values in?  Maybe that will give you some insight to where the issue is happening.  Or another approach, a Debug.Print Eval(qdf.Parameters(x).Name) prior to the calls would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VBA, why not create this as a Run time Query?

```
Dim strSQL As String, rst As Recordset, varData As Variant
Dim intFields As Integer, intRecords As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim rec As String, fld_type As Integer

strSQL = "SELECT tblRegistration.ID, tblRegistration.TypeCode, CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStart]) AS Reg1, " & _
         "CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStop]) AS Reg2 FROM tblRegistration WHERE " & _
         "((tblRegistration.TypeCode = 'T' Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = 'S' Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = 'F') AND " & _
         "(CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStart]) Between " & Format([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStart], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
         " And " & Format([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStop], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & ")) OR " & _
         "((tblRegistration.TypeCode = 'T' Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = 'S' Or tblRegistration.TypeCode = 'F') " & _
         "AND (CDate([tblRegistration].[RegStop]) Between " & Format([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStart], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
         " And " & Format([Forms]![frmRegBilling]![RegStop], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & "));"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: Hmm, that I should  have figured our myself too :-|. I never escaped special characters in SQL strings in VBA (\/). You see, never too late to learn. This approach did the job though. THX!

Comment: @Art Glad you have it sorted. Good luck ! :)